# How to use 2 JDateChooser as a searching tool in JTable?

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jdbc

I'm having problem with showing database values in my Jtable. I don't know how to use `JDataChooser` as a searching tool in `JTable`. I want the process like this, if `JDateChooser1` is select to `08-17-2017` and `JDateChooser2` is select `09-17-2017`
the `JTable` will only show the values that having that date between `08-17-2017 - 09-17-2017`. The format of the Date is (`MM-dd-yyyy`).

I have this method and as a testing I put the method to a button. I also want to know where I can put this method to be able not using a button. Auto search when I'm done selecting the dates.

sales is my table name in mysql and Date is the column name.

```
private void Dated() {
    try {
        String value1, value2;
        value1 = jDateChooser1.getDate().toString();
        value2 = jDateChooser2.getDate().toString();
        String sql = "select * from sales where Date = '" + value1 + "' and '" + value2 + "'";
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = pst.executeQuery();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Prepared statement with direct values in query? Never, never do so

Comment: I'am just a student. I don't know the don'ts in making a system. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing some information in your query :

1. **show the values that having that date between 08-17-2017 - 09-17-2017** you have to use **between** keyword in the query `should be select * from sales where Date between date1 and date1` and not `=`
2. because you are using prepapred statement don't use concatination of the query and values.
3. beside Date is reserved keyword in MySQL instead you have to put it between two ``

Your code should look like :

```
Date value1 = jDateChooser1.getDate();
Date value2 = jDateChooser2.getDate();
String sql = "select * from sales where `Date` between ? and ?";
pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
pst.setDate(1, value1);
pst.setDate(2, value2);
rs = pst.executeQuery();
```

Comment: @VhongMarvinNavarraVillanuev can show me the full error?

Comment: (1+) for the PreparedStatement example. @VhongMarvinNavarraVillanuev, `It showing some errors. incompatible types` - well then fix the errors. We don't have access to your database. We don't know how you have defined the data in your database. You have been given a simple example of how to create a PreparedStatement so the SQL is readable and maintainable. It is up to you to make sure the data passed to the PreparedStatement is in the format that your database expects.

Comment: thank you @camickr i agree with you also i suspect that the OP use `String value1, value2;` instead of Date

Comment: I format the date in my database as a varchar(String)

Comment: @VhongMarvinNavarraVillanuev then instead you have to format your date as a String in java take a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

Comment: @VhongMarvinNavarraVillanuev The first question is why you would you use a varchar( String )? Databases have different data formats and you should use the appropriate format. But if you do want to use a String, then convert the Date to a String and use the appropriate method from the PreparedStatement to set the parameter to the proper data value. Read the PreparedStatement API for more information.

Comment: Hmmmm. Okay guys. @YCF_L The error is ("incompatible types: java.util.Date cannot be converted to java.sql.Date"). I changed the format of my date column to DATE. I'm not good in formulating the codes. Sorry guys. I'm just a beginner. Hope you can understand my knowledge in coding.